# Everything is set to Bounciness 0 - Why am I still bouncing?

Tags: unity, physics

I am creating a platformer where rather than manipulating the character to get them from the beginning of the level to the end, you manipulate the world.  Thus, when you want to make the character 'jump' over a gap, you actually use the land like a slingshot and 'fling' them.

This is all working well and good save for one thing - whenever I pull my land down and my player falls into it again, it begins to bounce - aggressively so!

I have made EVERYTHING out of a new physics material with 0 bounce, and I set my default physics to 0 bounce.

My player is a rigidbody2D that is moving itself along on top of other rigid bodies.

What gives? Why, even though EVERYTHING is set to 'no bouncing allowed' does my game turn into a bouncy-house whenever i start to play?

EDIT: Here is a video of the behavior:

[FlingyJump - Bouncing Issues](https://vimeo.com/164128790)

EDIT: I have noticed a correlation to the bounce occurring and the spring being active.  It have noticed that two things are happening:

1) The spring is for some reason transferring force through to the ground piece while being stretched out.

2) The player is bouncing *before even ever hitting the ground*.  I don't know quite how that is possible but it seems like as soon as it is enters the original position of the rigidbody2D for the ground piece it bounces.

Comment: This sounds very unusual. Can you show us a video of the symptoms, a screenshot of the inspector parameters for your player and world rididbodies/colliders, and a snippet of the code you're using to move the level? I'm suspecting penetration & restitution may be at work here...

Comment: You've checked the usual suspects I guess? Project gravity, mass of the rigidbody, collider sizes, scripting that you forgot you did?

Comment: If you have discovered what was wrong, post it as an answer instead of editing it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it seems that the spring is constantly exerting force on the platform even when I'm not actually allowing the platform to move. While that was expected, what I did not expect was that apparently the force was being transferred through the platform into the player upon contact.

I've since restructured the entire way the mechanic works, but I thought that I'd add that bit of insight in case this might help someone else someday.